# The normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a normal random vector $X\sim N(0,\Sigma_1)$, and $Y=BX+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\Sigma_2)$. I want to know whether the vector $(X^T,Y^T)^T$ is still a normal random vector, and what's the distribution of the new vector?

Comment: I lost something that $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Two important facts you need to bear in mind when you face this kind of questions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normally_distributed_and_independent

- If two normally distributed random variables are independent, then they are jointly follows a multivariate normal distribution. It should be also covering case considering two multivariate normal random vectors.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation

- Any affine transformation of multivariate normal stills has a
  multivariate normal distribution.

With these two facts, it is not hard to see that:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} X \\ \epsilon\end{bmatrix} \sim
\mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \Sigma_2 \end{bmatrix}\right) $$

and

$$ \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ B & I \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ \epsilon \end{bmatrix}
$$

So the new random vector also has a multivariate normal, and you can try to write down the new mean vector and covariance matrix by applying the formula inside wiki.

Comment: Thanks alot! I understand that!